# How to force figures positions for only 1 section?

Tags: floats, positioning

Instead of using

```
\usepackage{placeins}
```

to force **all figures** to be in their sections, I need **only 1 specific section** that has multiple subsections, to have the figures in their corresponding subsections.

How can I do that?

Comment: I will simply use `[!htb]` and the package `flafter`. Some figure could be displaced after the subsection to avoid gaps in text due to pagebreaks, but for sure the alternative of fix absolutely the position (`[H]` of the `float` package) will be worse.

Comment: According to the manual, `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` causes **all** sections to add `\FloatBarrier`.  You should be fine using `\usepackage{placins}` to just add `\FloatBarrier` where needed.